# Test of functional API fails

Tags: tensorflow2.0

For testing i tried to convert the generator of https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/generative/dcgan.ipynb#scrollTo=6bpTcDqoLWjY into functional API, but it does not work.
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Does someone know what i do wrong?

I replace the generator code with:

```
def make_generator_model():
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,))

  l = layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False)(inputs)
  #l1 = layers.BatchNormalization(l)
  l2 = layers.LeakyReLU(l)
  l3 = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256))(l2)
  l4 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False)(l3)
  #l5 = layers.BatchNormalization()(l4)
  l6 = layers.LeakyReLU()(l4)
  l7 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False)(l6)
  #l8 = layers.BatchNormalization()(l7)
  l9 = layers.LeakyReLU()(l7)
  l10 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh')(l9)
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=l10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from missing () after LeakyRely()() . The working code is:

```
def make_generator_model():
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,))

  l = layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False)(inputs)
  l1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(l)
  l2 = layers.LeakyReLU()(l1)
  l3 = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256))(l2)
  l4 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False)(l3)
  l5 = layers.BatchNormalization()(l4)
  l6 = layers.LeakyReLU()(l5)
  l7 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False)(l6)
  l8 = layers.BatchNormalization()(l7)
  l9 = layers.LeakyReLU()(l8)
  l10 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh')(l9)
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=l10)
```